# Imprimir desde PHP a impresora Fiscal Epson TM - H6

Tags: php, impresora, epson

buenos días.

Actualmente en mi trabajo tenemos un programa web que funciona en un supermercado en donde cada caja tiene una impresora fiscal y va imprimiendo sus boletas.

Entendiendo lo que ya está hecho me dijeron que se tuvo que instalar un archivo .ocx y algo de ActiveX para imprimir, el sistema está hecho en visual basic .asp.

Nos pidieron investigar si desde php se puede hacer lo mismo (me imagino que es para cambiar el sistema que tenemos ).

Yo tengo una impresora para hacer pruebas y esta es una Epson TM-H6000III Model: M147G

y buscando por internet, en google y en la propia pagina de epson o en foros e leído que esto es posible si la impresora está conectada al servidor.

Estos son los links que he encontrado:
+ [Link 1](https://fioriticarlos.wordpress.com/2017/03/09/impresora-fiscal-desde-php-mediante-ocx/)
+ [Librería en github](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) Pero creo que no acepta el modelo que tengo.
+ [Foro en el que se habla del tema](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/impresora-fiscal-epson-php-677049/)
+ [Página de epson que encontré](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5322&scat=47&pcat=3)

Quizás me estoy expandiendo mucho pero se puede hacer esto? Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Cada computadora va a tener instalado PHP o solo lo tendras en un servidor? ya que lo mas probable es que solo puedas imprimir desde el servidor y este tendra la impresora conectada.

Comment: aplicación en servidor, y como tu dices y yo también leí, sólo se podría imprimir con la impresora conectada al servidor, actualmente se está ocupando un archivo .ocx. No hay alguna forma de llamar a ese archivo desde php o desde el cliente para imprimir?

Comment: Verifica si puedes instalar la impresora en el cliente y al darle control+p en el navegador te muestra como opcion esa impresora, si la impresora requiere algo mas especializado tambien podrias intentar hacer un plugin para el navergador que estas usando.

Comment: por lo que tengo entendido ocupa una ocx y mediante activeX mandan a imprimir, la impresora que yo tengo de prueba no me aparece en las Impresoras del sistema y en la aplicación para imprimir una boleta solo veo: obj.ImprimirBoletaFiscal(Boleta);. Esta es la impresora que tengo [LINK](https://epson.cl/Soporte/Punto-de-venta/Impresoras-h%C3%ADbridas/Epson-TM-H6000IV/s/SPT_C31CB25014) por si sirve de algo

Comment: Como dicen. Tienes que tener los driver de la Impresora Fiscal en el servidor para poder imprimir la boleta. Ahora, dependiendo de la impresora y sus driver puedes ejecutar un comando desde el mismo PHP o desde otro lenguaje (como C o C++) para mandar a imprimir. Si son varias cajas de pago tendras que tener en todas PHP y los driver de la impresora. Cada una seria un Servidor conectado a una misma Bases de Datos.

Comment: claro, te entiendo, actualmente se tiene instalado un archivo .oxc en cada caja y que por activeX se manda el comando de impresión a la epson. Instalar php en cada caja sería un cacho para un supermercado